# Is it possible to connect a raspeberry pi to a 3.2" TFT LCD touch panel?

Tags: touchscreen, raspberry-pi

I am wondering if i can connect a raspberry Pi to [this](http://www.sainsmart.com/home-page-view/sainsmart-3-2-tft-lcd-display-touch-panel-pcb-adapter-sd-slot-for-arduino-2560.html)? How hard would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and almost no work required. The documents on the page you link to have datasheets and .cpp libraries. Pretty much if you know how to wire things together on a breadboard, granted a bigish one you can use it.

I suggest you do some research or try something so you have an actual question to ask.

Comment: How is that not an actual question?  Do you mean to say "a more specific question"?

Comment: Grammatically speaking it is a question, yes. As far as this website is concerned, that is not a question. So to answer your question: no I did not mean to say "a more specific question."

Comment: If I understand correctly, when questions are tagged as "not a real question" it's supposed to be because (for a common example) it's not something that can have a definitive answer.  I'm still not clear on what you think is wrong with this question.

Comment: Well it got 2 downvotes and I was not one of them, so clearly other people agree. Any question that can be aptly answered with "Yes, not very" does not belong on this website. Questions are supposed to be narrowly tailored yet just open-ended enough such that somebody who answers has a clear roadmap of the information they need to include in order to enlighten the asker yet cannot answer in one sentence. I.E. "How come when I connect my RPI as shown to this TFT LCD the following results happen rather than what I was expecting? What am I doing wrong and is there a standard practice for this?"

Comment: So you seem to be saying that it's not okay to ask if something is possible, but it's okay to say "xyz is failing: why?" even when the answer could very well be "because it's not possible".  Why?  And what's wrong with asking if something is possible.  I can't see what principle you're appealing to in making that claim.  (I guess if you have a simple and direct answer to those questions great: we'll wrap this up.  Otherwise let's move this to meta.)

Comment: The point of a question is to provoke an impartment of knowledge. Asking if something is possible does not provide that opportunity.